# #undefined в адресной строке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Для плавный прокрутки использую данный код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar-default ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {

        // prevent default anchor click behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        // animate
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 400, function() {
            // when done, add hash to url
            // (default click behaviour)
            window.location.hash = this.hash;
        });
    });
```

При клике на ссылку в адресной строке добавляется `#undefined` вместо значения  `hash` этой ссылки.

[Верстка](http://fh9989f8.bget.ru/claymore/#undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` внутри функции, вызываемой при завершении анимации, указывает на элемент, для которого была вызвана анимация. В данном случае, сначала на `html`, затем на `body`.

Имеет смысл сохранить `a` в отдельную переменную перед вызовом анимации. Например, так: `var that = this;`, после чего использовать `window.location.hash = that.hash;`

Итоговый код (я убрал `html` из `html, body`, чтобы функция вызывалась лишь один раз):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".navbar-default ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e)         
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = this;
        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 400, function() {
            window.location.hash = that.hash;
        });
    });
});
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjtxg4yf/).

Comment: Помогло, но теперь не работает e.preventDefault() в строку добавляется #home, #about, #contact....

Comment: @neoman в какую строку добавляется? Значение в адресной строке меняется в коде: `window.location.hash = that.hash;`

Comment: в адресной строку D:/works/web/claymore/index.html#home

Comment: @neoman повторюсь: `#home` там появляется из-за присвоения в коде: `window.location.hash = that.hash;`. Если не нужно отображать якорь в адресной строке, то достаточно удалить эту строку.

Comment: чудно! благодарю

Answer (score 0):

В том, что вы пытаетесь взять значение там, где его нет:

```
window.location.hash = this.hash;
                       ^^^^^^^^^
```

`this` в данном контексте - просто HTML-элемент, у него нет свойства `hash`. Вы можете получить адрес (href) ссылки, по которой кликнули, следующим образом:

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
```

Это создаст jQuery-обертку над текущим элементом, а затем получит атрибут href. не забудьте также заменить и более ранние вхождения.

Comment: Фраза _вы пытаетесь взять значение там, где его нет_ верная, но дело не в том, что якобы у DOM Element'a `<a>` нет свойства [.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/hash), а в том, на что указывает `this`.

Comment: @Regent мда, не знал.